# Why does the form element take up 100% of the width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form element which I want to take up the same width as its children, with no margin, but no matter what I do the browser makes its width + margin take up 100% of the width.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="container">

  <form method="GET" action="http://localhost/search" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="search centered">
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="text" name="query" class="searchbar" placeholder="What do you want to search?" />
        <button type="submit" class="search-button">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

and the css:

```
    @import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.search * {
  height: 35px;

}

.searchbar {
  width: 450px;
}
.brandname {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 500%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #1f0e3e;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.input-container{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: #e3e3e3;
    outline-width: 1px;
  }

  .searchbar{
    margin-left: 5px;
  }

  .search button {
    background-color: rgba(152,111,165,0.38);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    outline-width: 1px;
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: #e3e3e3;
    color: white;
}

.search input{
  outline-width: 0px;
}

form{
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yk9xjz9k/1/) is a fiddle where you can see that even if you force the form to have a small width, the browser forces a left-margin to take up the rest of the space.

How can i get rid of this margin and make the form automatically take up the space of its child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding display table to the `form` element will make it auto size to it's children elements.

```
form {
     display:table;
    }
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bnah6jLe/

## Why the form is 100% width by default

By default forms in most browsers have their display type set to `block`. In the specification for `block` context it is defined as follows.

> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the
>   left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right
>   edges touch)

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting

In short `display:block` is 100% width unless specified otherwise.

### Side Note

**Question:** Why was `table` used for this example instead of something like `inline-block`.

**Answer:** I used `table` instead of `inline-block` because display context such as `block` and `table` are used as containing elements and do not group. Display context like `inline-block` and `inline-table` are used for child elements that are meant to be grouped together. It's a small difference but I thought considering form is usually meant as a container table would be more appropriate.

Comment: can you say why the browser was forcing 100% width before?

Comment: @user3494047 My answer has been updated to include the reasoning.

Comment: Why do you use `table` instead of something like `inline-block`?

Comment: @KodosJohnson
I used `table` instead of `inline-block` because display context such as `block` and `table` are used as containing elements and do not group. Display context like `inline-block` and `inline-table` are used for child elements that are meant to be grouped together. It's a small difference but I though thought consider that form is usually meant as a container `table` would be more appropriate.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation.